# Three.js React Fiber - Transparent background

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using react fiber, and cannot figure out how to get the background of my child scene to be transparent

This is my root component with the main Canvas

```
export const Splash = () => {
  const { intensity, distance, color, ambientIntensity } = useControls('Main lights', {
    intensity: { value: 9, min: 0, max: 200, step: 0.5 },
    distance: { value: 100, min: -100, max: 100, step: 0.5 },
    color: "#7c0505",
    ambientIntensity: { value: 0.5, min: -3, max: 3, step: 0.1 },
  });
    
  return (<>
      <Canvas
        dpr={window.devicePixelRatio}
        onCreated={({ gl }) => {
          gl.setClearColor(0xFF0000, 0);
          gl.autoClear = false;
          gl.clearDepth()
        }}
        gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: true }}
        camera={{ fov: 65, position: [0, 0, 30] }}>
        <Main>
          <ambientLight intensity={ambientIntensity} color={color} />
          <RadialGradientPlane />
        </Main>
        <ApplyEffects>
         <RadialGradientPlane />
        </ApplyEffects>
        
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

The `Main` Component simply just renders a child scene

```
function Main({ children }) {
  const scene = useRef()
  const { gl, camera } = useThree()
  useFrame(() => {
    gl.autoClear = false
    gl.clearDepth()
    gl.render(scene.current, camera)
  }, 1)
  return <scene ref={scene}>{children}</scene>
}
```

This IS transparent, if i remove the ApplyEffects component i see the RadialGradientPlane and my normal document background colour.

It's something to do with the ApplyEffects component, which is:

```
import { Effects } from '@react-three/drei';
import { UnrealBloomPass, RenderPass, WaterPass } from 'three-stdlib';
export default function ApplyEffects({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }}) {
  const waterPass = useRef<WaterPass>(null!);
  const composer = useRef<EffectComposerGeneric<WebGLRenderTarget>>(null!)
  const { size, camera } = useThree();
  const aspect = useMemo(() => new Vector2(2046, 2046), [])
  const [scene, setScene] = useState<Scene>();
  const {strength, threshold, radius} = useControls('Bloom', {
    threshold: { value: 0.1, min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.01 },
    strength: { value: 1.5, min: 0, max: 10, step: 0.01 },
    radius: { value: 0.05, min: 0, max: 1, step: 0.01 },
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    if (composer.current) {
      composer.current.setSize(size.width, size.height)
    }
  }, [size])
  useFrame(() => {
    composer.current?.render();
    if (waterPass.current) {
      waterPass.current.time += 0.05;
    }
    composer.current.renderer.autoClear = false
    composer.current.renderer.clearDepth()
  }, 2);
  return <>
    <scene ref={setScene}>{children}</scene>
    <Effects ref={composer} disableGamma={true} disableRenderPass={true}>
      <renderPass scene={scene} camera={camera} />
      <waterPass ref={waterPass} attach="passes" factor={0.6} />
      <unrealBloomPass
        threshold={threshold}
        strength={strength}
        radius={radius}
        resolution={aspect} />
    </Effects>
  </>;
}
```

I feel like I've tried everything here, i cannot figure it out!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's an example of the same issue: [small example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bloom-hdr-workflow-forked-ocno2q?file=/src/App.js)

If you remove the "Effects" the background is transparent and shows the white body colour.

Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue reported and [heavily discussed here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14104).

One of the solutions is [implemented here](https://github.com/mbalex99/threejs-unrealbloompass-transparent-background-example) and seem to solve the problem based on [this demo](https://mbalex99.github.io/threejs-unrealbloompass-transparent-background-example/).

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, i did try that one, https://codesandbox.io/s/bloom-hdr-workflow-forked-ocno2q?file=/src/App.js

I've updated the example to include it but it's still black

Comment: The idea of the fix is to modify the shader. In your example, I don't see any changes to the shader. You have probably missed that part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by modify the shader? I replaced the bloom pass by the one provided in the repo you shared, is there something else i was supposed to do?

Comment: I took a second look at your example and noticed that you've added the `fixed` bloom effect file, however, it is not used. On line 27 you are using an effect named `unrealBloomPass` but the imported effect has the name `UnrealBloomPass` and is unreferenced. If I change `unrealBloomPass` to `UnrealBloomPass`, the compiler complains because the file of fixed effect is written on TypeScript while your project is on JavaScript. You will have to convert that TS code to JS or rewrite the effect using the shader code from the original TS file.

Comment: I'm using react fiber here, I'm using extend({ UnrealBloomPass }) up the top, which allows you to use it as a primative in jsx, I have already converted it to javascript as well?

Comment: In the original demo of this effect, it is instantiated like [this](https://github.com/mbalex99/threejs-unrealbloompass-transparent-background-example/blob/4ca1b8ed52cc69ebbf1a094dc4c9a192abfeeb6a/src/index.ts#L26) at runtime via TS. Based on the compiler complaint, I'm unsure if the same instantiation can be done via JSX.

Comment: I think that's just because you don't understand how react fiber works, it's exactly the same, anyways, i found this: https://github.com/Mugen87/three.js/commit/551e7b5640b76e0e966b40e1cf9b2a1cb7122e95 which making this change to the custom Bloom pass seems to fix the issue

Comment: Hey @ShannonHochkins, since my answer helped you to find the right solution, would you mind picking it as a solution? Thanks!